# Error for exec a sparql query into JS script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sparql, dbpedia

Beginning on sparql, wishing to execute a SPARQL query for the display in my "abstract" div, I encounter an error that I can not eliminate.
So I post my message to have an opinion (and a solution?) To finally display the result of my request.

Here is my error:

> jquery.min.js:4 GET
>   http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=PREFIX%20dbpedia2%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%20PREFIX%20Abs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20SELECT%20%3Fabstract%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fs%20dbpedia2%3ACivil_engineeringe%22%40en%3B%20Abs%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%7D&format=json&callback=jQuery111006239110193011803_1512251513037&_=1512251513038
>   net::ERR_ABORTED

Here is my script :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
        var query = [
            "PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>",
            "PREFIX Abs: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>",
            "SELECT ?abstract",
            "WHERE {",
            "?s dbpedia2:Civil_engineeringe\"@en;",
            "Abs:abstract ?abstract",
            "}"
        ].join(" ");

        var queryUrl = url+"?query="+ encodeURIComponent(query) +"&format=json";
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: queryUrl,
            success: function( _data ) {
                var results = _data.results.bindings;
                for ( var i in results ) {
                    var res = results[i].abstract.value;
                }
            }
        }).done(function(res){
            $("#abstract").html(res);
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="abstract">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A SPARQL query is basically made of triple patterns matching RDF triples. I can't see any triple pattern. An RDF triple consists of subject, predicate, and object. Why do you have the variable `?s`? What would be the predicate? Assuming that you're talking about the resource `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Civil_engineering`, Why do you append an `e` and then double quote to the prefixed URI? And why the language tag? RDF literals can have language tags, but a URI is never a literal. And literals do only occur in object position of a triple (resp. triple pattern) ?

Comment: Lomg story short, it looks like you missed basic understanding of RDF and/or SPARQL and just copy pasted something which is far away from a valid SPARQL query. This doesn't work. I'd really suggest reading at least some basic RDF/SPARQL tutorial. It's not that difficult to learn, especially if you have a computer since background.

Comment: To give you the working query (I assume here that you want to get theEgnlish abstract of the resource `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Civil_engineering)`: `PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT ?abstract WHERE { 
dbr:Civil_engineering dbo:abstract ?abstract 
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
}`